# Add values when X columns exist

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file that looks something like this

```
InvoiceDate    Bill Person     BAN    Type    Amount    Amount-Expenses   GreenFee      TaxAmount    FinalTotal
1524753593    Jennifer Doe     39193  S       33.30      20               2             1            75
1524753593    Jason Bourne Doe 395931 S       27.00      11               2             1            57.33
1524753593               Feature    D    15    12.00    64.20
1524753593    Jean-Pierre Doe  395931 S       53.10      44               2             1            12.33
1524753593               Feature    D    12    5.00     74.32
1524753593    Jamie Doe        39193  S       35.30      42               2             1            53.11
```

I need to get the total for the file...it has several thousand entries like the sampling above. I need the total for the last column but iff the number of columns is greater than 8.

I thought about using grep to get only the columns I need into a temporary file but give that the file can easily be osscillate between 30 to 100+ MB I believe it'd be faster not to involve an intermediate file. I thought about reverseing the file grabbing all the numbers from the first column where the type is S but I wasn't sure exactly how to do that via awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NF>=8 && NR>1 { entries++; sum+=$8 } END { print "Total for column 8:", sum, "over", entries, "records with this value present." }' inputfile
```